Type "SourceOfFundsType" already exists in the schema. It cannot also be defined in this type definition
When ever I try to use SourceOfFundsSupportingDocumentInputin my @Field decorator, I get the error that

caughtException: Type "SourceOfFundsType" already exists in the
schema. It cannot also be defined in this type definition.

If I comment the @Field line or use another class such as UploadedDocumentInput in my  @Field decorator, the error vanishes. Correct way should be using SourceOfFundsSupportingDocumentInputin@Field decorator. How can I use that ?
src/generated-cbms-api-client/models/SourceOfFundsType.ts
/* generated using openapi-typescript-codegen -- do no edit */
/* istanbul ignore file */
/* tslint:disable */
/* eslint-disable */

export enum SourceOfFundsType {
    EMPLOYMENT = 'EMPLOYMENT',
    SAVINGS = 'SAVINGS',
    WINNINGS = 'WINNINGS',
    MARITAL = 'MARITAL',
    REAL_ESTATE = 'REAL_ESTATE',
    TRUST = 'TRUST',
    INVESTMENT = 'INVESTMENT',
    OTHER = 'OTHER',
    COMPANY = 'COMPANY',
    COMPANY_CAPITAL = 'COMPANY_CAPITAL',
    LOAN = 'LOAN',
    PRIVATE_CAPITAL = 'PRIVATE_CAPITAL',
    GRANT = 'GRANT',
}


src/app/accounts/dto/common-account.input.ts
@InputType()
export class UploadedDocumentInput {
  @Field(() => String)
  documentType: string;

  @Field(() => GraphQLUpload)
  frontSideDoc: FileUpload;

  @Field(() => GraphQLUpload, { nullable: true })
  backSideDoc?: FileUpload;
}



@InputType()
export class SourceOfFundsSupportingDocumentInput extends OmitType(UploadedDocumentInput, ['documentType'], InputType) {
  @Field(() => SourceOfFundsType)
  documentType: SourceOfFundsType;
}



@InputType()
export class SourceOfFundsInput {
  @Field(() => [SourceOfFundsTypeOrString], { description: 'Source of funds' })
  sourceOfFunds: (SourceOfFundsType | string)[];

  @IsArray()
  @IsOptional()
  @ValidateNested({ each: true })
  @Type(() => SourceOfFundsSupportingDocumentInput)
  @Field(() => [SourceOfFundsSupportingDocumentInput], { description: 'Source of funds supporting docs', nullable: true }) // this line causes the error
  sourceOfFundsSupportingDocs?: SourceOfFundsSupportingDocumentInput[];
}

